# Cant get a button in a popup menu for chrome extension to work

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My goal is to just add simple text when ever I click the button to the input box.
I've tried everything there's out there.

The only time the code actually works is when I put the "addEventListener" to the button in the outter scope of the .js file, but it only works once and not because I clicked on it.

here's the code snipet.

**Manifest.Json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Crm Goal Checker",
  "description": "This App Checks",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <style type="text/css">
         body {
        margin: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      input {
      margin: 10px;
       width: 28px;
      }
      #container {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    </style>
<script language="javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Goals List</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <span>Weekly Goal</span>
      <input id="textBox" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
      <span>Currently At</span>
      <input type="text" value="3" readonly="readonly"/>
    </div>
    <button id="buttonId">Click</>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function changeText() {
    document.getElementById('textBox').value += '4';
}


 if(document.readyState === 'loading') {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
      document.getElementById("buttonId").addEventListener('click', 
      changeText());
     },false);
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("buttonId").addEventListener('click', 
      changeText());
    }
```

Comment: changeText() invokes the function immediately. Remove () to pass the function reference properly.

Comment: worked.. thank you!!